# Bash - listing programs in all subdirectories with directory name before file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I don't need to do this in one line, but I've only got 1 line so far.

```
find . -perm -111 +type f | sort -r
```

What I'm trying to do is write a bash script that will display the list of all files in the current directory that are executable (z to a). I want the script to do the same for all subdirectories. What I'm having difficulty doing is displaying the name of the subdirectory before the list of executable files in that directory / subdirectory.

So, to clarify, desirable output might look like this:

```
program1
program2
SubDir1
program3
SubDirSubDir2
program4
SubDir2
program5
```

What I have right now (the above code) does this. Its not removing /path and it isn't listing the name of the new directory when directories are changed.

```
./exfile
./test/exfile1
./test1/program2
./test1/program
./first
```

Hopefully that was clear.

Comment: Do you mean that for each directory you want to show all directories first, followed by the files?  What sort order do you want the directories to follow?

Comment: To clarify, I want to print the executable programs in the current directory. And then, print the name of the first sub-directory and list each program under that. And then do it for all sub-directories (recursively).

Comment: @paddy added new information to the original post

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

I changed the permission to `-100` because maybe some programs are only executable by its owner.

```
for d in $(find . -type d); do
    echo "in $d:"
    find $d -maxdepth 1 -perm -100 -type f | sed 's#.*/##'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you.

```
find . -type d | sort | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c "find {} -type f -maxdepth 1 -executable | sort -r"
```

The first find command lists all directories and sub directories and sort them in ascending order.

The sorted directories/sub-directories are then passed to `xargs` which calls `bash` to find the files within the directory/sub-directory and sort them in descending order.

If you prefer to also print the directory, you may run it without `-type f`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` on all directories and combine it with `-print` (to print the directory name) and `-exec` (to execute a find for files in that directory):

```
find . -type d -print -exec bash -c 'find {} -type f -depth 1 -perm +0111 | sort -r' \;
```

Let's break this down.  First, you have the directory search:

```
find . -type d -print
```

Then the command to execute for each directory:

```
find {} -type f -depth 1 -perm +0111 | sort -r
```

The `-exec` switch will expand the path wherever it sees `{}`.  Because this uses a pipe operator that is shell syntax, the whole thing is wrapped in `bash -c`.

You can expand on this further.  If you want to strip the directory name off the files and space our your results nicer, something like this might suffice:

```
find {} -type f -depth 1 -print0 -perm +0111 | xargs -n1 -0 basename | sort -r && echo
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the sorting requirement makes this tricky - the "for d in $(find...)" command is clever, but hard to control the sorting.  How about this?  Everything is z->a, including the directories, but the awk statement is a bit of a monster ;_)

`` find `pwd` -perm 111 -type f |
 sort -r |
 xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c "dirname {};basename {}" |
 awk '/^\// {dir=$0 ; if (dir != lastdir) {print;lastdir=dir}} !/^\// {print}' ``

Produces

`/home/imcgowan/t/t3
jjj
iii
hhh
/home/imcgowan/t/t2
ggg
fff
eee
/home/imcgowan/t/t1
ddd
ccc
bbb
/home/imcgowan/t
aaa`